# SteamVR creating loading screen flicker when recording using FFMPEG in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, heatmap, steamvr

I have a heatmap plugin integrated in my Unity VR game(with SteamVR). The plugin uses eye tracking information to generate live heatmaps as the user gazes at different elements in the game. As the heatmaps are generated, the whole camera view(user's) is overlayed with heatmaps info and written to a MP4 file using FFMPEG.

---

The whole process works fine. But I have an annoying problem where during the recording the user's camera view is not stable and keeps flickering and stops only when the recording is stopped. It interrupts the smooth flow of his game
For now, I've narrowed down the code which causes the trouble,

```
        public void Write(byte[] data)
    {
        if (_subprocess == null) return;

        _stdin.Write(data);
        _stdin.Flush();
    }
```

From my understanding, It is in this part of the code stdinput is invoked to write to the file system. So, I surmise that the problem must be with accessing the file system which in turn must have caused some time delay when each frame is written in the update method. Correct me if i am wrong here. 
[image]

The loading screen which appears during every frame write looks something like above. It interrupts the smooth flow of the game and also makes the recording useless as the user keeps focusing on the flicker rather than the actual objects of interest. I would really be grateful if someone shows light on the issue here?

Comment: Do you want to record what the user is seeing? If that's the case I suggest you record the video first and then convert it to mp4 using FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the file system always takes a huge amount of time. Try offloading that work to another thread or a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to use Coroutine in Unity to offload the Write part of FFMPEG. But, It won't solve the issue; I still see the flicker. Do you think its a bad idea to write to mp4 file(accessing the file system and causing delay) while recording the scene. Or is there a way to keep it in the memory till the end of recording and write to the file system altogether?

Comment: You could keep a certain buffer in memory and save it to disk every x seconds or when the buffer is full. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the FFMPEG API and thus can't give you any specific code examples